# Zend Framework/Form: custom elements not shown on error

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, error-handling

I've added a custom element type to render raw html into forms. In addition i do custom error handling (to highlight the errored items and add the error-msg as tooltip).

Everything works. Except my custom (raw html) elements are not being shown at all if the custom error handling methode catches an validation error.

Has someone an idea why my raw html items are being stripped out of the markup if the form validation fails?

Form:

```
class Sample_Form_Process extends Zend_Form
{

    [...]

    public function init()
    {

    [...]

        $this->addElement('rawText', 'spacer', array(
            'value' => '<br class="cl"/><div class="border-bottom"></div>',
        ));

    [...]

    }

    [...]

    public function highlightErrorElements()
    {
        foreach($this->getElements() as $element) {
            if($element->hasErrors()) {
                $element->setAttrib('class', 'error tooltip');
                $element->setAttrib('title', $element->getMessages());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProcessController class:

```
class Sample_ProcessController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    [...]

    public function addAction()
    {

        [...]

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {

            [...]

            } else {
                $form->highlightErrorElements();
            }
        }
    }

    [...]

}
```

RawText class to render custom form element:

```
class Zend_Form_Element_RawText extends Zend_Form_Element
{
    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
    {
        return $this->getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the $_POST when you submit the form?

Comment: $_POST contains only the data of the (native) form elements:
http://pastebin.com/255ruDyE

Comment: I don't see any data for spacer element in there.

Comment: Why does the data for the spacer elements has to be inside the $_POST? It should only contain form input/values and no markup, shouldn't it?

Other markup of fields (classes, wrapper, etc.) aren't inside the post, either. Or does Zend (re-)render the form on validation only with existing elements inside the $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `isValid()` method to your custom form element, to always return `true` so it passes validation.

```
public function isValid($value)
{
    return true;
}
```